# Have entire contents of the c drive as a folder how to make it bootable again

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, backup

I have every single file of my old c drive copied in a folder. I did this using linux, so I'm sure all files are backed up.
Now I want to return to that installation, but when I copy-paste files, computer doesn't recognize boot files, so it don't boot up.

I know it's not the most ideal backup method but I had to do it this way.
Now I'm experimenting on virtual pc but things I know didn't work

Comment: You cannot simply copy the system files and have a bootable Windows installation.  What you describe isn’t possible.  All you did was backup your personal files and potential the ability to restore your application settings.

Comment: Welcome to superuser Emrea. You have to reinstall system, go to settings, in update and security select recovery and reinstall from a system image, install disk or select recovery.  If you have been able to wipe your disk then get a install disk [cd or usb] from anywhere and use your windows install code when needed. You then can copy from your linux folder the personal data that has been copied but will have to reinstall apps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Linux to copy Windows files, since the permissions models
of the two operating systems are not compatible.
You should have backed up the **image**
of your hard disk, in order to be able to restore it.

I suggest to install Windows from boot media to the disk, wiping it out
in the process.
Re-install your applications and re-do all your settings.
Finally, copy your personal files from your backup.

Do not try to copy system folders - copy only your own data from wherever
you have stored it.
As a side-note, applications are not personal data, they need to be re-installed.